# One row selector in all Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Based on what you see below is the sample of a datagridview that an item has been selected.

[image]

Here is my question what if I have a more than 1 Datagridview? I mean 5 Datagridview like this.

[image]

All of them contains 1 column only. Based on the 1st image, the row selector or the blue one select an item.

My question is how can I make all of the datagridview only have one row selector?

What happens is when i selected each of them all of it has a row selected 5 selections.

How can I make 1 row selector for all of them.

Thinking of changing the Selection Color but I think that's not applicable.

TYSM for future help.

Comment: 5 datagrid or more? then if you click 1st row in 1st datagrid the 2nd datagrid will also select the 1st row and so on? this is what you want to achieve?

Comment: No sir, Example I click datagridview1 so there is a blue selector, If I click datagridview2 the row selector from datagridview1 will be gone because I selected a new one and so on, For example a datagridview with many columns and `CellSelect SelectiondMode` One row selector in all 5 datagridview

Comment: then insert `clearselection` for example you click datagrid1 then insert `dg2.clearselection() dg3.clearselection()` and so on. then if you click datagrid2 then insert `dg1.clearselection() dg3.clearselection()` and so on.

Comment: You mean `datagridview1.ClearSelection`? just add this code everytime i click a cell?

Comment: yah. if you click datagridview2 then make sure that you clear the selected cell in dg1 or dg3 or dg4 and so on

Comment: Nice trick TYSM Sir, please make it an answer so i can accept it

Comment: Are the datagridviews grouped together in a GroupBox?

Comment: No sir, No groupbox

Comment: Are these 5 datagridviews the only datagridviews present in the form?

Comment: Yes sir only 5 datagridviews

Comment: @ShadowFiend, too late, posted it anyway. Just tell me if you tried this one and it works. Thanks.

Comment: @This one works sir but the first answer works also, I dont want to be bias so I will give you an upvote :D

Comment: @ShadowFiend, nah, don't need it. Thanks anyway. I just want to know if it works 'cause that's just derived from a _pseudo code_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this maybe it is more easy to edit if you add more grid

```
Private Sub ClearSelectedCells(ByVal Identifier As Integer)
    If Identifier = 1 Then 'for datagrid 1
        dg2.ClearSelection()
        dg3.ClearSelection()
    ElseIf Identifier = 2 Then 'for datagrid 2
        dg1.ClearSelection()
        dg3.ClearSelection()
    'and so on
    .
    .
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub dg1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dg1.CellClick
    ClearSelectedCells(1)
End Sub

'and other gridcellclick
.
.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an alternative, you can also try this approach:

```
Private Sub DataGridView_CellEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles _
DataGridView1.CellEnter, DataGridView2.CellEnter, DataGridView3.CellEnter, DataGridView4.CellEnter, DataGridView5.CellEnter
    Dim MyDataGrids() As DataGridView = {DataGridView1, DataGridView2, DataGridView3, DataGridView4, DataGridView5}
    For i = 0 To MyDataGrids.Count - 1
        If MyDataGrids(i).Name = sender.Name Then
            Continue For
        Else
            MyDataGrids(i).ClearSelection()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

`MyDataGrids()`  is an array of `DataGridViews`. If for example, the controls you need to check increases, just add the name of the `DataGridView` in this array and it will be included in the checking and clearing of selections. Don't also forget the `Handles` event. As you can see here, all of the five grids `.CellEnter` event are included so you don't have to *copy-paste* it to five separate events.